# Meteor pub/sub or method return, what will perform better?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'd like to know the proper decision for this Meteor scenario:

1. User click button
2. Client side code calls a server Method.
3. Method code calls mongoDB and generates a random array with some content from collection A.
4. Server save the given array as a new doc into collection B.
5. Generated array data must get printed to the DOM.

What is better for performance maters? Return the array directly from method.call or publish/subscribe B collection?

NOTE THAT:
a) Array content are 20(tops) string elements of less than 120 characters each.
b) Array data is not reactive.
c) User won't need new data until he clicks '0 button' again.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the client->method->server and server->pub/sub->client way.
This way you get queries in minimongo. Also about reactivity you can throttle it so it's not a huge issue. Returning data via method would make you need promises etc cause it will take time to get back to you. Unless you will execute some function in return function from the call.

about the C), client won't get new data the pub/sub will handle this. Client will only get new data if there is new data/update.

Comment: Thank you Kamil. I do use a callback on the meteor.call. I was wondering what consumes mor resourses,  callback or subscription

Comment: callback is cheaper due to lack of reactivity
there is quite huge debate if we really need real time data